# Getting a list for Gdal "Merge" in QGIS Graphical Modeller

Tags: qgis, gdal, merge

I am looking for a way to create an array from the attributes of a multipolygon layer for the algorithm "Gdal Merge".

In my layer I have stored file paths to .xyz-data that I want to read so they can be merged together.

[image]

I use the graphical modeling and expression manager for my algorithm which includes cutting.

Unfortunately, the expression manager does not show me any way to access the layers either. My knowledge of QGIS and the expression manager is not good enough either.

I tried something like this to get the attributes in an array, but it doesn't work:

`array(attributes ('Furz_1343ad30_bdd6_4ab7_b737_676a72e0b380'))`

[image]

Does someone has an idea for me?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on my own.

It is possible to get a list from the field, if the layer is loaded in the project and has a name. My code:

`string_to_array(aggregate(  'Furz', aggregate := 'concatenate', expression := "Field1", concatenator := ';'),';')`

The condition is, that the layer is already loaded.